# Main Method to be used by Test Class

Tags: java, object, testing, methods, program-entry-point

Hi so i have my main class but im having trouble figuring out how to output my code from my test class. I dont understand even though tried many ways how to output the simple addition and subtraction of two fractions as it should do in my main method but can't seem to get it into my test class.

here is my code for the class with all the functions:

```
package rational;

 public class Rational {

private int numer, denom;

 //constructors
    public Rational(){
        int num = 1;
        int den = 2;
        reduce();
    }
    public Rational(int num, int den){
    numer = num;
    denom = den;
    reduce();
    }
    public Rational(Rational x){
    numer = x.numer;
    denom = x.denom;
    reduce();
    }

   //setters
    public void setNumer(int num){
    numer = num;
    reduce();
    }
    public void setDenom(int den){
    denom = den;
    reduce();
    }
    public void setRational(int num, int den){
    numer = num;
    denom = den;
    reduce();
    }

     //getters
    public int getNumer(){
    return numer;
    }
    public int getDenom(){
    return denom;
    }

    //Copy method
    public void copyFrom(Rational x){
    numer = x.numer;
    denom = x.denom;
    reduce();
    }

    //Equals method        
    public boolean equals(Rational x){
    if (numer / denom == x.numer / x.denom){
    return(true);
            }
    else {
    return(false);
        }
    }

    //Compare to method
    public int compareTo(Rational x){
    if (numer / denom == x.numer / x.denom){
    return (0);
    }
    else if (numer / denom < x.numer / x.denom){
    return (-1);
    }
    else{
    return (1);
        }    
    }

    //Find greatest common divisor
    static int gcd(int x, int y){
    int r;
    while (y != 0) {
    r = x % y;
    x = y;
    y = r;
        }
    return x;
    }

    //Rational Addition            
    public void plus(Rational x){
    int greatdenom = x.denom * denom;       
    int multx = greatdenom / x.denom;
    int mult = greatdenom / denom;
    denom = x.denom * denom;
    numer = (x.numer * multx) + (numer * mult);
    reduce();
    }

    //Rational Subtraction
    public void minus(Rational x){
    int greatdenom = x.denom * denom;       
    int multx = greatdenom / x.denom;
    int mult = greatdenom / denom;
    denom = x.denom * denom;
    if (x.numer > numer){
    numer = (x.numer * multx) - (numer * mult);
        }
    else {
    numer = (numer * mult) - (x.numer * multx);
        }
    reduce();
    }

     //Multiplication       
    public void times(Rational x){
    numer = numer * x.numer;
    denom = denom * x.denom;
    reduce();
    }

    //Division        
    public void divBy(Rational x){
    numer = numer / x.numer;
    denom = denom / x.denom;
    reduce();
    }

     //Fraction simplifier        
    private void reduce(){
    int divisor;
    divisor = Rational.gcd(numer, denom);
    numer = numer / divisor;
    denom = denom / divisor;
    }

@Override
    public String toString(){
    if (denom == 1){
    return numer + "";
    }
    else{
    return numer + " / " + denom;
    }       
}
   }
```

Comment: so where is the main method ? I can't see it.

Comment: Where's your test class?

Comment: @justAJAVAGUY where is you `test` class and `main` method.

Comment: @LKTN.25 that was my other class in which i wanted to call

Comment: @DavidWallace this is my other class in which i wanted to call using the main

Comment: @RajS.Rusia This is my other class however I'm having trouble with my main method

Comment: Right, but if you want people to help you, it's better if you post _the class that you're having trouble with_.  Kind of hard to help you with stuff we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a Rational (rather than void) in your plus method.

```
public Rational plus(Rational x){
   //do addition stuff.
    return new Rational(//what numerator be//,//what denom should be//)
    }
```

As a suggestion, I would make all these operator methods static and take in 2 parameters too.  And then you would use "getters" for each of the two rational numbers' numerators and denominators.

Like this:

```
public static Rational plus(Rational r1, Rational r2) {
    int r1Num=r1.getNum();
    int r1Denom=r1.getDenom();
    int r2Num=r2.getNum();
    int r2Denom=r2.getDenom();
    //do all your plus stuff
    return new Rational(//new num, //new denom);
}
```

Comment: How would do i take in two parameters and which method would i do that?

Comment: Do it for the plus method.  It would look like the above.  You have to create those geNum() and getDenom methods in your Rational class.  Would make your code even cleaner to put all your math functions in a separate class.

Comment: Thank you this helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

try following code as a test class.

**Sample Code Test class**

```
public class TestRational
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Rational rational= new Rational(2,3);
    rational.plus(rational);
    System.out.print(rational.toString());
  }
}
```

**Output Will be**

```
4 / 3
```